# Save data in coredata with relationship classes?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have one class `Place` &  other class as `Address`.Now one place has only one address so i have create to one relationship.Now when i am trying to save the place then i am not able to do it .Below is the code i wrote for this functionality.

```
if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            placeInfo =  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "PlaceInfo", into: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext) as? PlaceInfo
        } else {
            placeInfo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "PlaceInfo", into: appDelegate.managedObjectContext!) as? PlaceInfo
        }
            var cordinates:[String] = []
            placeInfo?.title = Place.shared.title ?? ""
            placeInfo?.desc = Place.shared.desc ?? ""
            placeInfo?.id = "Place_" + String(Utility.shared.currentTimeStamp())
             let spotLocation  = Place.shared.address

            if let lat = spotLocation?.lat, let long  = spotLocation?.long {
                cordinates = [lat.toString(),long.toString()]
            }
            let address  = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "PlaceAddress", into: appDelegate.managedObjectContext!) as? PlaceAddress
            address?.street =  "Street"
            address?.landmark  = "LANDMARK"
            address?.city = "MYCITY"
            address?.state =   "SATTE"
            address?.state =  "INDIA"
            address?.pincode  =  "1256325"

            placeInfo?.isuploaded = true
            if let spotid = placeInfo?.id {
               // saveMediaToDB(id: spotid)
            }
            placeInfo?.address_rel = address
```

**Placeinfo class**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension PlaceInfo {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<PlaceInfo> {
        return NSFetchRequest<PlaceInfo>(entityName: "PlaceInfo")
    }

    @NSManaged public var desc: String?
    @NSManaged public var hasmedia: Bool
    @NSManaged public var id: String?
    @NSManaged public var isuploaded: Bool
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var address_rel: PlaceAddress?
    @NSManaged public var files_rel: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for files_rel
extension PlaceInfo {

    @objc(addFiles_relObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToFiles_rel(_ value: FilesInfo)

    @objc(removeFiles_relObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromFiles_rel(_ value: FilesInfo)

    @objc(addFiles_rel:)
    @NSManaged public func addToFiles_rel(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeFiles_rel:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromFiles_rel(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

Comment: Why do you optional downcast `as? PlaceInfo` and `as? PlaceAddress`? The classes definitely exist at compile time. A forced downcast must not fail otherwise it reveals a developer / design error. Then you get rid of all the ugly question marks. And you should do the conditional compiling `if #available(iOS 10, *)` also for the  `PlaceAddress` initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added the below line of code?

```
do {
    try managedObjectContext.save()
} catch {
    fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
}
```